# Did Project Horizon draft any proposals for small arms weapons for astronauts?

Tags: the-moon, weapon, lunar-base

The 1959 Project Horizon discusses building a base on the Moon, and also, according to the Wikipedia article, mentions weapons to be used for (of course) fighting the Soviets attacking the Moon base, on the Moon itself.

To quote it:

> "The base would be defended against Soviet overland attack by man-fired weapons:
>
> Unguided Davy Crockett rockets with low-yield nuclear warheads
>
> Conventional Claymore mines modified to puncture pressure suits"

However, there is no citation for this on Wikipedia, and I'm curious if other weapons were proposed.

It seems ludicrous to only arm soldiers on the moon with only rocket launchers sporting nuclear warheads.

What other weapons, if any, did they propose in Project Horizon?

If Project Horizon didn't propose anything else, has anything been proposed since then?

Comment: A quick skim through both volumes of the Project Horizon documents turned up no references to personal weapons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same ideas (and in some cases the same text) get repeated in a bunch of places (occasionally without modification) and without source which was not a compelling start. There were no references to actual arms, small or otherwise, in the readily available Volume I and II of the Project Horizon report. One commercial bookseller publishing a collection of Project Horizon stuff claims that Volume III of the report [remains classified](http://www.cgpublishing.com/Books/9781989044070.html), and that seemed likely to be the one with the goods in, disappointingly.

With sufficient searching though, I finally turned up [this little reference from Small Arms Review](http://www.smallarmsreview.com/archive/reference.05-2013.cfm), which observed that it was no longer classified and even went as far as to provide a nice free download link, full of all sorts of goodies. They obtained access from Shrivenham Small Arms Library which is not a facility open to the public. This is the only source I found for the document, so it doesn't necessarily have particularly good provenance... compare the awkwardness of getting Volume III compared to the ease of finding I and II. It still seems to have been either only partially scanned or was partially redacted, as it only contains chapter 3, and no other part (such as an index). There's at least another 100 pages out there somewhere...

That aside, it gives us things like this:

[image: Handheld claymore weapon]
[image: Claymore weapon use]

the key observation being that the backblast of a claymore is somewhat less hazardous in a vacuum, making it practical to use one onna stick.

As promised by the unsourced wiki text, conventional claymore mines and Davy Crockett-type man-portable rocket launchers were also considered, though the latter included a provision for non-nuclear warheads. Also mentioned are grenade launchers and a pistol that fired buckshot (for ease of aiming). There's other scifi goodness in there too, such as

> A proposal to study an Electron Accelerator as a weapon was reviewed and it appears feasible to deveolp a linear accelerator capable of projecting a focused beam of gamma radiation of sufficient density to develop adequate doses of neutron and gamma radiation in the target material

which sounds like complete technobabble garbage to me, but who knows. They do at least admit that such a thing would be too hard to develop in a useful timescale and probably too heavy, too.

Anyway, dangling wiki reference issue solved, and a fascinating bit of work regardless of whether it is genuine or not.

---

With regards to future work, one reference that pops up a few times, probably because of its name, is the 1965 work [The Meanderings of a Weapons Oriented Mind When Applied In A Vaccum Such As On The Moon](https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/3038458/The-Meanderings-of-a-Weapon-Oriented-Mind-When.pdf) with a splendid subsection entitled "*Possible Weapon Concepts Whose Feasibilities Have Not Been Determined But Are Presented As Ideas To Stimulated Thinking*", which seems to roughly translate as a weapons list for a scifi RPG, complete with specs and illustrations. Not as cheesily awesome as the ones in the Project Horizon report above, alas.

I've no doubt other work has been done since, but is likely to be of a less cheerily speculative nature and more of a practical one, and as such seems likely to still be classified.

---

If anyone from the US was feeling particularly keen, maybe they could make an FOIA request? Assuming any other copies of the work still exist and it was indeed declassified, it might be possible to locate them or at least see if this one is a work of fiction.

Comment: Interesting find. The second picture though does look more like illustration to a Sci-Fi book rather than to a real-life report (the look of mountains, the antenna on the helmet, enemy falling too artistically, why land in such a narrow valley?). Also what about recoil from such a mine-stick? Wouldn't it seriously destabilize the astronaut firing it?

Comment: @LeoS there's some back-blast to counter the recoil, so it won't be as serious as you might expect. It wouldn't be like firing a gun, in that regard. The illustration does seem a bit out of place compared to the rest of thedocument, I note.

Comment: @LeoS check out the "flight simulator" picture on page 47 of Volume 1.  It's pretty artistic as well.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, that one is artistic too. But that spiral antenna though... There is depiction of anticipated space suit on page 16 of Volume 1. It shows straight antenna. Why would a picture from Vol.3 show less realistic suit than already pictured in Vol.1 and a spiral non-realistic sci-fi antenna on top of the helmet?

Comment: @LeoS those skate things on their feet are pretty crazy too.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Maybe that's a cut-out section of ski? Like it was done in earlier days to walk on snow in north polar area. They originally thought stuff will sink into regolith on the moon.

Comment: These troubling images are freaking me out, so I'm handling it the way I handle everything else in life, by asking another SE question [Was a hand-held Claymore mine-based space weapon or anything similar described in fiction before it was proposed in reality? (ca. 1959)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/225887/51174)

Comment: @OrganicMarble they're mentioned as "dust insulating boots", I think. I seem to recall there was some uncertainty as to the nature of lunar dust before Apollo 11 actually landed? Maybe they were intended to deal with crossing deep cold dust during the lunar night. Maybe that's worth another question too...

Comment: The 1965 document is fantastic, especially this on page 5: "The laser, for practical application as a weapon, is 20 years away."

Comment: @Dragongeek ahh, laserguns, fusion and flying cars. The trifecta of scifi disappointment.

Comment: Awesome reply, thanks. I have only one question, which perhaps you came across while skimming through this. WHY was any of this stuff proposed at all? What is the problem with a simple projectile weapon, similar to a standard military rifle, modified for operation in vacuum? Why invoke ray guns and other exotic weapons? To draw attention? Political reasons?

Comment: @AlphaCentauri there's a bit of blurb about it in the earlier part of the report, but basically: the environment is _very_ hard on mechanisms, and shooting accurately was expected to be implausible in a spacesuit, hence the need for the little shotgun-pistol-thing. The rayguns were probably just in there in the hopes of getting research money, as it wasn't entirely clear at the time how impractical they'd be (though there were clearly some inklings of the problems, even back then).